# hp-uft record checkpoint in Application area attached Object Repositoriy

Tags: hp-uft

How do i copy a recorded checkpoint from my Local Object Repository to the Application Area repository.

Steps attempted:

1. in the test click record button and create a Bitmap capture
2. not sure how to move this recorded checkpoint to the attached application area Repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export your local repository, then you can add it to the application area